# No Preparation mission items available in Preparation system

Tags: elite-dangerous

I recently pledged allegiance to Zachary Hudson. From reading forums and wiki pages, I understand his Preparation missions are supposed to be completed as follows:

- Go to a system listed in the Powers Preparation tab
- Go to a station (not sure if it's any station or has to be a specific one)
- Access Powers Contact in the stations Contacts menu
- **Pick up Restricted Intel from Powers Contact**
- Deliver intel to a controlled system

[image: meenates info 1]

[image: meenates info 2]

I had a nice little mining route going with my Type-6, but I abandoned it to try and get some merit points by doing preparation tasks. I traveled a huge distance to get to a Preparation system (Meenates), and now **there's no option to pick up intel at any station in that system**. There's an option to nominate the Meenates for expansion in every Powers contact menu, but I don't have any nominations to use currently.

[image: prep system power contact panel]

From what I've read on forums, someone somewhere in this system should be able to sell/give me up to 10 intels (I'm at allegiance level 1), but I've visited every station and no such luck.

Am I missing something here? Is it too late in the weekly "cycle" to get intel? Is it because my faction can't afford to expand here this cycle? I'm with Hudson, and we can't afford to expand *anywhere* this cycle, so I thought that didn't matter.

*So why not just try another Preparation system?*

The Prep systems are pretty far apart for my current FSD, so before I travel a huge distance to another Prep system, or just go all the way back to my route, I'd like to plan my moves to be efficient. If there's a reason to target some Prep systems instead of others, that'd be great to know in advance.

Comment: Hm, Hudson doesn't have enough surplus CC to prepare Meenates (or any of the other systems on the list), that *could* be the reason…but I'm not sure.

Comment: I thought Preparation was going to a controlled system and transporting goods *to* the system you want prepared?

Comment: @Yuuki it is confusing so I've double checked, and I'm posting pics to clarify

Comment: @Yuuki Not for Hudson, he collects intel from the systems being prepared (apparently), opposite the usual Control -> Preparation

Comment: @TimStone I thought the CC might be it, but that would imply that if your controlled systems dont make enough money, you'd perpetually be unable to expand? Like, upkeep outweights profit? Im new to Power play missions, so that may be the case, I'm not sure.

Comment: Yeah, it's a huge balancing act. More fortification could lead to additional surplus CC next cycle, or their could be a deficit which might lead to a less profitable system revolting, which would in turn free up more CC later down the road…admittedly the mechanics could use some improvement.

Comment: @TimStone makes sense I guess, this week should be all fortification to ensure (hopefully) preparation next week. Id definitely accept that as an answer if you want to post it, as its the only logical conclusion I can think of. Just wish I'd asked before I hauled my ass 300 ly for nothing, haha.